# why string replacement does not change the string in some cases?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

I am trying to replace the `µ` with `micro` in a string. It could replace some strings but it does not perform for some of them, for example, it changes `20.0+-1.8% hemolysis at 50µM` to `20.0+-1.8% hemolysis at 50microM` but it does not change it in this case: `0% hemolysis at 312 to 0μg/ml`. What could be the reason?

```
rep = {"±": "+-", "µ": "micro"}
rep = dict((re.escape(k), v) for k, v in rep.items())
pattern = re.compile("|".join(rep.keys()))
activity = pattern.sub(lambda m: rep[re.escape(m.group(0))], rows[i + 1].string.strip())
```

Even the `replace()` did not change it:

```
activity = rows[i + 1].string.strip().replace('±','+-').replace('µ': 'micro')
```

**Solution:**
The comment by @user2357112 could help to find a simple solution:

I changed the dictionary to this:

```
rep = {"±": "  +-  ", "µ": "micro", '\u03BC' : 'micro'}
```

Comment: `replace('μ': 'micro')`? Is the colon a typo?

Comment: It looks like you could skip a few steps using [maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans) and [translate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.translate)?

Comment: One of those characters is U+00B5 MICRO SIGN. The other is U+03BC GREEK SMALL LETTER MU.

Comment: [Here's this fwiw](https://tio.run/##RU5LCsIwFNznFI@I2GCtn25E8DBpE9tgk5TkIRTxUC7cddUD9EoxKYKbYQbm1w/YWlOeexeCqBGu8KTTm16Abnc0Bzp9EteqdjbJefzLF8GqiwGPrtD8LtFx47NYwghZAbbKNBE5glDCbBDqlptGEifTCj2soZXadoNXHqKpPJ4ALRzmsdnrjhZLW8dRZnGFkd4pg1nMLuU35Tzm4GVtjQBe2Yf8OawTWTrNclhoPMwYCeEL)

Comment: @user2357112 thanks, how to change my code then?

Comment: Change it to look for both variants, or separately apply Unicode normalization before you try to match.